# $elemMatch output in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with one element

```
mongos> db.products.findOne();
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "product_code" : "345678",
        "variations" : [
                {
                        "size" : "L",
                        "price" : 1000
                },
                {
                        "size" : "M",
                        "price" : 800
                }
        ]
}
```

Now when I do an $elemMatch query below

```
db.products.find( {product_code: "345678"}, { "variations": { $elemMatch: { size: "L" } } } );
```

I get the output as below

```
{ "_id" : 1, "variations" : [ { "size" : "L", "price" : 1000 } ] }
```

My question is why the "product_code" field with the value 345678 is not displayed in the output of the $elemMatch query ? any ideas ?? is this a bug or I am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because when you provide a [projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) parameter in your [`find`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find) call, you need to specify all the fields you want.

So you need to add `product_code` to your projection object:

```
db.test.find({ product_code: "345678"}, 
             { product_code: 1, 
               variations: { $elemMatch: { size: "L" } } } )
```

Comment: but I have not provided a projection parameter in my find call.. db.products.find( {product_code: "345678"}, { "variations": { $elemMatch: { size: "L" } } } );

Comment: @user641887 You have; the second parameter in your `find` call (the one with the variations $elemMatch) is the projection parameter.